# C# Nested Lists: Getting an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: c#, linq, list, object, singleton

I'm encountering a problem when I try to fill a List of List of strings. (Each List represents a page to print, with each string in the list being a line of text on a page). The List of List of Strings represents the entire text of a document. I need this `List<List<string>>` so I can pair each document with it's respective Config File.

I'm going to copy the relevant code here:

Here's my Variables and the accessor and mutator I use for my `List<List<string>>`

```
private static readonly TemplateSingleton instance = new TemplateSingleton();
private List<string> lineOfPage;
private List<List<string>> _streamList;

public List<List<string>> StreamList
{
    get { return _streamList; }
    set { value = _streamList; }
}
```

And here's the method that's breaking:

```
#region Generate Lists

//Takes the stream of data and adds it to a list that can be processed.
public void GenerateLists(ref List<List<string>> arg, ReportConfig cfg)
{
    if (TemplateSingleton.Instance.CurrentReportNum == 0)
    {
        TemplateSingleton.Instance.CFGList = new List<ReportConfig>();
        TemplateSingleton.Instance.ReportsList = new List<Templates>();
    }

    TemplateSingleton.Instance.CFGList.Add(cfg);
    TemplateSingleton.Instance.ReportsList.Add(TemplateSingleton.Instance.ChooseTemplate(cfg));

    if (StreamList == null)
    {
        //Create a list of array values to hold them.
        StreamList = new List<List<string>>(arg.Count);
    }

    int counter = 0;
    foreach (List<string> argString in arg)
    {
        //Build a new array with the size equal to the number of lines.
        lineOfPage = new List<string>();

        //If the string isn't null...
        if (argString != null)
        {
            //for each line of each page...
            foreach (string str in argString)
            {
                //...If *that* string isn't null...
                if (str != null)
                {
                    //...add the string to the array of lines on a page.
                    lineOfPage.Add(str);

                 }
             }
             //list.Add(lineOfPage);

             //A lot to unpack here. Add each line of a page, where the line of a page isn't empty, as an array, then convert the result back to a list.
             StreamList.Add(new List<string>(lineOfPage.ToArray().Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToList()));
         }

         //Add the list to my List of Lists
    TemplateSingleton.Instance.ListOfStringLists.Add(StreamList);
}
```

When I run the code, my other lists initialize just fine. But when it tries to do

```
StreamList.Add(new List<string>(lineOfPage.ToArray().Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToList()));
```

It breaks. It's not the LINQ I use, either. When I run it as just

```
StreamList.Add(argString);
```

I get the same error. I've tried a lot of different things. The exact location of the error (that I can see) is that when the line that initializes my StreamList (StreamList = new List>()) executes, it doesn't actually initialize. In fact, it still shows as having a value of null (when I step through the method.)

I've only been coding for a couple months now. I've learned a lot of cool things but there are properties about vars that I use (like List) that might have limitations I'm unfamiliar with. I'd appreciate any help you all can offer. Thanks!

***Edit: This question has been answered. It was a silly typo that broke it. If anyone has the same problem, I'll post the updated code that works.***

```
private static readonly TemplateSingleton instance = new TemplateSingleton();
private List<string> lineOfPage;
private List<List<string>> _streamList;

public List<List<string>> StreamList
{
    get { return _streamList; }
    set { _streamList = value; }
}
```

Or

```
public List<List<string>> StreamList { get; set; }   //Automatically implemented property.
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Look at your setter: `set { value = _streamList; }`. That's broken. Now would be a good time to learn about automatically implemented properties...

Comment: @Jon Skeet Yeah? How should I set it?

Comment: Well you'd have `set { _streamList = value; }` rather than copying the existing value into the property parameter... but it would be simpler to use `public List<List<string>> StreamList { get; set; }`

Comment: @JonSkeet OH! I'm going to give that a try. Brb.

Comment: There's also no need for `arg` to have the `ref` modifier in the code you've shown us, either...

Comment: @JonSkeet So I tried doing this : public List<List<string>> StreamList { get; set; }  It didn't work. Are you supposed to do that when you declare the variable? Or is it done where I've been doing the others?

Comment: Also, for the "ref" modifier, I think that's just an artifact of a different idea that I had and chose not to implement. I'll go ahead and toss it.

Comment: "It didn't work" doesn't say *anything* about what happened. And that completely replaces both the `_streamList` variable and your existing `StreamList` property declaratoin.

Comment: Actually nevermind, I'm an idiot! Your idea worked. I made a typo when I tried it earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the setter:

```
set { value = _streamList; }
```

This should be

```
set { _streamList = value; }
```